# Get the background-image url from an existing <div> and/or add another attribute to background-image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background-image

I am trying to update an existing background-image with linear-gradient. At the moment my CMS is creating an background-image, but I can't change the opacity with linear gradient. I just want to darken the background-image per CSS.

My solution -> Get the url from all background-image div classes (.bg-image) to set "setAttribute" a new background-image tag.

```
   var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("bg-image");
    for (var i = 0, n = elems.length; i<n; ++i){
        var img = document.getElementsByClassName('bg-image')[i],
            bi = style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1);

        img.setAttribute('style', 'background-image: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),url("' bi +'"));');};
```

Comment: can u post ur html as well?

Comment: you could just override the .bg-image class in a new css file right? you don't need to use jquery or javascript for this at all

Comment: Do you need js for this?

Comment: @JeremyC. It hasn't worked with :before or other css stuff.

Comment: have you tried important?

Comment: Yep. Unfortunately nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You listed jQuery as a tag, so I assume that's an option despite you using vanilla:

```
$(".bg-image").each({
    $(this).css({
        backgroundImage:"inear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),"+$(this).css("backgroundImage"));
    });
});
```

**No jQuery solution:**

If you want vanilla though, the problem you have is that `bi = style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1);` should probably be `bi = img.style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1);`.

Also, don't set styles like this

```
img.setAttribute('style', 'background-image: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),url("' bi +'"));')
```

Instead, use

```
img.style.backgroundImage="linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),url("+bi+")";
```

And since you're adding it as an url back anyway, there's no need to extract it out with `slice`. Also, no need to select the element again.

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("bg-image");
for (var i = 0; i<elems.length; i++){
    var bi = elems[i].style.backgroundImage;
    elems[i].style.backgroundImage="linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),"+bi;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need javascript for this. Here is a **Pure CSS** solution:

The principle is to use the `:before` selector and put styling on that.

Obviously some details will vary based on how stuff is placed within your background-styled DOM node but you can use `z-index` to place content above the overlay if necessary (*alternatively*, if the background image is set with css, you could set it on `#content:before`, move the `rgba` to `#content` and then the z-index stuff wouldn't matter ).

Run the code snippet below to see it in action (I used a red tint so you could see that it wasn't just a dark image).

```css
#content {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url("http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/city/1/");
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  color: white;
}
#content:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  /* you don't need a gradient with this method */
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
</div>
```

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? Can you put together a fiddle? Does it work in the code snippet?

Comment: Sorry for my englisch. The CSS solution havn't worked with my CMS. It might by out of my control because of server-side scripts or smth.

Comment: Don't worry about your English when I said, "what does it mean?" what I meant was, "can you explain in what way it's not working". "Didn't work" doesn't tell me anything about the problem and a pure css solution is IMHO better (it's the point of CSS to do this sort of thing).